# How to stop two elements effecting each other?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm creating an animation https://codepen.io/adsler/pen/bGNWxOe and I've created a div class. I've adjusted this with css. It works. However, as soon as I introduce another div class, it's not only effected by the first, but there seems to be no way of selecting it with css.

So here is the original:

Html:

```
<div   
class="random">four<br>
three<br>zero<br>nine</div>
```

Css:

```
.random {background. 
color:red;background-image: 
linear-gradient(black, 
white); width: 10px; height: 
200px; font-weight: 900; 
position:relative; font- 
size:20px; left: 20x; 
top:60px; filter:sepia(0); 
color:black; border-radius: 
100px; box-shadow: 90px 90px 
30px 90px #000; text-align: 
center;}

.random {animation: turn 30s 
ease-in infinite; animation. 
direction: alternate. 
reverse;animation-delay: 
2s;} 

@keyframes turn {

0% 
{transform:rotate(1400deg);
width: 1px} 30%. 
{transform:rotatex(7000deg);  
font-size: 30px;} 40% 
{transform:rotatez(360deg); 
 width: 13em} 70%
{width: 10em;}100%
{opacity: 0.9;}
```

That's fine but then, when I introduce the next sequence, by way of a div class, I can't find the selector with css and the style is influenced by the first div.

```
<div 
class="starring">Starring
</div>


.starring {margin-top: 500px 
!important; font-size: 50px 
!important;}
```

So I tried specificity.

```
.random.starring {margin. 
 top: 500px 
!important; font-size: 50px 
!important;}
```

Still unable to select `starring` with css and style still influenced by previous div.

Comment: https://codepen.io/adsler/pen/bGNWxO --> 404

Comment: Do you have `margin. top` in your source, or is that just a typo here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are missing a closing `}` for your `turn` keyframe.

```css
@keyframes turn {
  0% {
    transform:rotate(1400deg);
    width: 1px
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotatex(7000deg);
    font-size: 30px;
  } 
  40% {
    transform: rotatez(360deg); 
    width: 13em
  } 
  70% {
    width: 10em;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}
```

And then for your second div, this will work:

```css
.starring {
    margin-top: 500px !important; 
    font-size: 50px !important;
}
```

Comment: Tried it still not able to adjust second div class `starring` https://codepen.io/adsler/pen/bGNWxOe

Comment: in the codepen make sure you change `.random>.starring` to `.starring`

Comment: and scroll down, you will see it in big text

Comment: check it out here: https://codepen.io/thomas-short/pen/MWYowYr

Comment: @Amg Just tagging you so you notice my comments

Answer (score 2):

In your codepen under the html section you have one too many ending 's in the first part.

Like this:

```
<div class="random">four<br>three<br>zero<br>nine</div></div>
<div class="starring">Starring</div>
```

Which should be:

```
<div class="random">four<br>three<br>zero<br>nine</div>
<div class="starring">Starring</div>
```

Next thing is - you don't end your animation in your css part

```
@keyframes turn { 
0%{transform:rotate(1400deg);
    width: 1px} 
30%{transform:rotatex(7000deg);  
    font-size: 30px;} 
40% {transform:rotatez(360deg); 
    width: 13em} 
70% {width: 10em;}100%
   {opacity: 0.9;}
```

Here you need a last } to actually wrap up the turn tag.

Like this:

```
@keyframes turn { 
0%{transform:rotate(1400deg);
    width: 1px} 
30%{transform:rotatex(7000deg);  
    font-size: 30px;} 
40% {transform:rotatez(360deg); 
    width: 13em} 
70% {width: 10em;}100%
   {opacity: 0.9;}
 }
```

Make these changes and it works as supposed.

```
.starring {
 color:red;
```

}

Works for me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take the time to review the [How to answer section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in order to post a good, self contained answer that addresses the question (which you correctly followed!) and kindly remove any salutations from the post as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

I feel best solution here would be giving css to 1 element.

Add position:absolute to 1 of the element. And further accordingly adjust the element wherever you want using margin-bottom and margin-left!